# How to start nethack on solaris 11.3?

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, sun, sunos

I downloaded this package from the package manager: http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/beta/info/0/pkg%3A%2F%2Fsolaris%2Fgames%2Fnethack@3.4.3,5.11-0.151.0.1%3A20101105T054109Z

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "downloaded" but everything you need to do is `pkg install nethack` (as root role) and then run it as any user. According to manifest binary should be in `/usr/bin/nethack`, so typing:

```
/usr/bin/nethack
```

in your terminal window should do. It is very likely `/usr/bin` is in your `PATH` so you can just type

```
nethack
```

and game should start.